# How to share image with description or title on All Social Sites in iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I want to share images with title or description on All social sites like facebook, google, LinkedIn etc. But when the user clicks on image one link is open how to integrate it. I am searching a lot and find one solution for integrating All SDK of social sites.I am trying to integrate with Facebook to share an image with the link.But I am not able to share. I am facing below issues when I share the image on Facebook.I implement all below question for facebook share.But I fail.Please tell me what I doing wrong in my code to solve my problem.And any other solution for this Please tell me.

```
error Domain=com.facebook.Facebook.platform Code=102 "(null)" UserInfo={error_reason=The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBAPIErrorDomain error 100.), error_description=Failed to authenticate the application because of app name mismatch.  Please check the application name configured by the dialog., app_id=00000000000, error_code=102

<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
    </array>

let content = LinkShareContent(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.co.in/")!, title: "google", description: "google.com", quote: "", imageURL: URL(string: "https://www.google.co.in/1513255170789.jpg"))

 let shareDialog = ShareDialog(content: content)
        shareDialog.mode = .native
        shareDialog.failsOnInvalidData = true
        shareDialog.completion = { result in
            // Handle share results
        }

        try? shareDialog.show()
```

Comment: How does your code actually "fail"? with error message?

Comment: By using this code it opens the facebook app and when I click on post it redirects to my app without posting the post.